# Vue.js devtools not detecting Vue.js in standalone installation, already allowed access to file URLs

Tags: vue.js, installation, devtools

I have a vue.js + laravel installation project on my local server where the Vue.js devtools detects Vue.js and I'm able to use it. However, when I do a standalone Vue.js installation using 'vue create', Vue.js is not detected by devtools. I already allowed access to file URLs under chrome extension but it is still not working. The devtools was detecting Vue.js in the laravel version just fine without allowing access to file URLS.

Is there something else basic that I'm missing to get Vue.js devtools to work? There must be a simple step I missed because there should be loads of people creating fresh Vue.js projects on local server and getting devtools to work.

I'm using 'npm run serve' to run Vue.js in localhost, is this supposed to be detected by Vue.js devtools by default?

Answer (score 0):

solved by reinstalling Vue.js 2 instead of the Vue.js 3 preview version as of 2020-08-26.